# How can I pop-up a print dialog box using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a page with a "Print" link that takes the user to a printer-friendly page.  The client wants a print dialog box to appear automatically when the user arrives at the print-friendly page.  How can I do this with javascript?

Answer (score 291, accepted):

```
window.print();
```

unless you mean a custom looking popup.

Comment: A bit old, but I like to add ... window.print();setTimeout("window.close()", 100); .  This waits enough time for the rest of the page to load, but then hangs until the print button on the print dialogue is pressed, or cancelled, and then neatly shuts the tab down again.

Answer (score 45):

You could do

```
<body onload="window.print()">
...
</body>
```

Answer (score 25):

I like this, so that you can add whatever fields you want and print it that way.

```
function printPage() {
    var w = window.open();

    var headers =  $("#headers").html();
    var field= $("#field1").html();
    var field2= $("#field2").html();

    var html = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>";
    html += '<html lang="en-us">';
    html += '<head><style></style></head>';
    html += "<body>";

    //check to see if they are null so "undefined" doesnt print on the page. <br>s optional, just to give space
    if(headers != null) html += headers + "<br/><br/>";
    if(field != null) html += field + "<br/><br/>";
    if(field2 != null) html += field2 + "<br/><br/>";

    html += "</body>";
    w.document.write(html);
    w.window.print();
    w.document.close();
};
```

Comment: This worked like a charm for me. Needed to allow popups in browser. I'm not sure the "close" ever gets executed, since the tab never goes away.

Comment: It works, but open a new tab. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 13):

If you just have a link without a click event handler:

```
<a href="javascript:window.print();">Print Page</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

I do this to make sure they remember to print landscape, which is necessary for a lot of pages on a lot of printers.

```
<a href="javascript:alert('Please be sure to set your printer to Landscape.');window.print();">Print Me...</a>
```

or

```
<body onload="alert('Please be sure to set your printer to Landscape.');window.print();">
etc.
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can tie it to button or on load of the page.

```
window.print();
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer has already been provided. But I just wanted to elaborate with regards to doing this in a Blazor app (razor)...

You will need to inject IJSRuntime, in order to perform JSInterop (running javascript functions from C#)

IN YOUR RAZOR PAGE:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
```

Once you have that injected, create a button with a click event that calls a C# method:

```
<MatFAB Icon="@MatIconNames.Print" OnClick="@(async () => await print())"></MatFAB>
```

(or something more simple if you don't use MatBlazor)

```
<button @onclick="@(async () => await print())">PRINT</button>
```

For the C# method:

```
public async Task print()
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("printDocument");
}
```

NOW IN YOUR index.html:

```
<script>
    function printDocument() {
        window.print();
    }
</script>
```

Something to note, the reason the onclick events are asynchronous is because IJSRuntime awaits it's calls such as InvokeVoidAsync

PS: If you wanted to message box in asp net core for instance:

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("alert", "Hello user, this is the message box");
```

To have a confirm message box:

```
bool question = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", "Are you sure you want to do this?");
    if(question == true)
    {
        //user clicked yes
    }
    else
    {
        //user clicked no
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is helpful @James-Heffer, but you can even simplify it further (if only for the Print portion) buy NOT creating your own JavaScript method of `printDocument` and just call `await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("print");` and just call the given method directly.

Comment: Could this in any way be applied to an ASP.NET MVC 5 scenario ? I'm running on .NET 4.5

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    const _print = () => {
        window.print();
    }
</script>
```

or

```
<body onload="window.print();"></body>
```

see the documentation here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but after fighting with this similar issue, I figured out a way to open a print screen and **NOT** have to open a new tab, and **not** have to enable popups.

Hopefully, this helps someone else.

```
/*
    Example:
    <a href="//example.com" class="print-url">Print</a>
*/

//LISTEN FOR PRINT URL ITEMS TO BE CLICKED
$(document).off('click.PrintUrl').on('click.PrintUrl', '.print-url', function(e){

    //PREVENT OTHER CLICK EVENTS FROM PROPAGATING
    e.preventDefault();

    //TRY TO ASK THE URL TO TRIGGER A PRINT DIALOGUE BOX
    printUrl($(this).attr('href'));
});

//TRIGGER A PRINT DIALOGE BOX FROM A URL
function printUrl(url) {    

    //CREATE A HIDDEN IFRAME AND APPEND IT TO THE BODY THEN WAIT FOR IT TO LOAD
    $('<iframe src="'+url+'"></iframe>').hide().appendTo('body').on('load', function(){
        
        var oldTitle    = $(document).attr('title');                //GET THE ORIGINAL DOCUMENT TITLE
        var that        = $(this);                                  //STORE THIS IFRAME AS A VARIABLE           
        var title       = $(that).contents().find('title').text();  //GET THE IFRAME TITLE
        $(that).focus();                                            //CALL THE IFRAME INTO FOCUS (FOR OLDER BROWSERS)   

        //SET THE DOCUMENT TITLE FROM THE IFRAME (THIS NAMES THE DOWNLOADED FILE)
        if(title && title.length) $(document).attr('title', title);
        
        //TRIGGER THE IFRAME TO CALL THE PRINT
        $(that)[0].contentWindow.print();

        //LISTEN FOR THE PRINT DIALOGUE BOX TO CLOSE
        $(window).off('focus.PrintUrl').on('focus.PrintUrl', function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();                                            //PREVENT OTHER WINDOW FOCUS EVENTS FROM RUNNING            
            $(that).remove();                                               //GET RID OF THE IFRAME
            if(title && title.length) $(document).attr('title', oldTitle);  //RESET THE PAGE TITLE
            $(window).off('focus.PrintUrl');                                //STOP LISTENING FOR WINDOW FOCUS
        });
    });    
};
```

Comment: Great documentation! A+

Answer (score -7):

if problem:

```
 mywindow.print();
```

altenative using:

```
'<scr'+'ipt>print()</scr'+'ipt>'
```

Full:

```
 $('.print-ticket').click(function(){

        var body = $('body').html();
        var ticket_area = '<aside class="widget tickets">' + $('.widget.tickets').html() + '</aside>';

        $('body').html(ticket_area);
        var print_html = '<html lang="tr">' + $('html').html() + '<scr'+'ipt>print()</scr'+'ipt>' + '</html>'; 
        $('body').html(body);

        var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=600,width=800');
        mywindow.document.write(print_html);
        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10'</html>'
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        //mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;
    });
```

Comment: why are you concatenating this together anyway? '<scr'+'ipt>print()</scr'+'ipt>'

Comment: I think this person is trying to get around some sanitizer. Either way, this isn't a valid answer.