# How to execute keybord shortcut CTRL + P by clicking a link using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

I want to print a page to do so I have to click <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, so I would like to make a link to ease the process. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242182/how-can-i-pop-up-a-print-dialog-box-using-javascript. Please use google or built in stackoverflow browser efficiently...

Comment: How about just calling `window.print();`??

Comment: @SzybkiSasza I have searched on google, I got results using php, so I tought asking here, I also searched here and I didn't get what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes. sometimes window.print is not working. But ctrl+p event is working fine. If anybody knows the issue

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You don't need to simulate a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> keypress to print the window - you can just call `window.print()` when required instead.

Comment: In most cases, this works fine, `window.print()` is blocking, while <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> is not.  For example, trying entering the following in the dev console and then executing print via the two methods.  `window.print()` will delay the timeout until the user closes the print dialog, while <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> won't.
`window.setTimeout(()=> console.log('timeout callback'), 5000);`

Comment: Hey!! how did you solve this issues?? Can you please help me out.