# How to Save webpage to PDF similarly to Ctrl+p

Tags: javascript, php

I have a webpage that I made using PHP and HTML with CSS, it is a document, When I try to save the doc as a PDF using Ctrl + p it works perfectly, but I want to add a button to the webpage that automates this task, when the user clicks that button, the PDF will be generated.

I tried `Html2pdf.js` but it just takes a screenshot of the page, is there any other method to generate PDF with selectable text? Or maybe automate the ctrl+p, remove header and save as PDF.

Comment: seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711523/how-to-execute-keybord-shortcut-ctrl-p-by-clicking-a-link-using-jquery

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute keybord shortcut CTRL + P by clicking a link using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711523/how-to-execute-keybord-shortcut-ctrl-p-by-clicking-a-link-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

It will generate the selectable PDF of your whole HTML page.

Here is how you can install it

```
npm install jspdf --save
```

Include the following Scripts in your project:

- jspdf.js
- jspdf.plugin.from_html.js
- jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js
- jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js

The code in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="ignorePDF">don't print this to pdf</p>
    <div>
      <p><font size="3" color="red">print this to pdf</font></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Following Javascript Code will open the popup and generate html to pdf.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();          
var elementHandler = {
  '#ignorePDF': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
  }
};
var source = window.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
doc.fromHTML(
    source,
    15,
    15,
    {
      'width': 180,'elementHandlers': elementHandler
    });

doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
```

For Further Detail Read the Documentation [here](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)